# Yadcf Angular Integration

Tags: angularjs, angular-datatables, yadcf

I have worked with **jQuery Datatables** and **Yadcf** in previous projects.

This time I wanted to integrate Yadcf in **Angular-Datatables**.

Normally you would attach the yadcf initialization right after the datatable or do this in a separate line with **yadcf.init()** however this doesn't seems to be possible when using Angular Datatables even though it's just a wrapper for the normal datatables.

Because of the fact that yadcf.init() needs the datatable object I tried to call the initialization within **initComplete**.

The debugger showed that Yadcf gets called but the whole Yadcf stuff doesn't get applied to the table.

There is no error shown in console or something.

**What's I want to know is the right way to integrate Yadcf to angular-datatables.**

Comment: Haven't tried with angular but I do know that other tried (and it worked for them). If you provide a jsbin/plunker I might be able to help a bit

Comment: Working plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/x7ugaXoM1H571DLMn5mc?p=preview

Comment: Take a look at this https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/issues/358#issuecomment-116163993

Comment: I read this before I posted my question here. I just thought there might be a shorter way to get things done.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of...